# how to set timeout function in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, settimeout, react-native-navigation

I am new in React-Native.
and I am trying to **set image delay to load function** in react native.

```js
              <Image  style={{  width:250, height: 250 }}
                source={require('../images/cart.png')}
                onLoad={() => {
                   this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
                }}
             />
```

I am trying this but it gets an error

```js
                 onLoad={() => {
                   setTimeout(function(){
                      this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
                  }, 3000);
                  }}
```

Comment: @ShibinRajuMathew  redirect after sometimes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you try this arrow function notation

```js
setTimeout(() => {
this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
}, 3000);
```